# iot hub android and ios get twin module

Tags: android, ios, azure-iot-hub

missing of documentations on connecting android and ios to device twin

Hey
I have tried to use a service that gives me back my twin but without success, there is no clear enough guide that gives the option to do so

please if anyone has an idea how to implement this like AWS IoT core like a shadow.
needs a solution in mobile native even better in a flutter

this piece of code I have tried but without success in ios native

```
IoTHubDeviceClient_GetTwinAsync
```